# VMware fusion 4 won't launch due to out of date, running guests

Tags: macos, install, vmware

When running the Upgrade Installer from VMware Fusion 3.1.3 to v4.0.1, this dialog pops up:

> A virtual machine is running with an older version of VMware Fusion.
>
> Please use the older version of VMware Fusion to suspend or power off all virtual machines.

I shut down all the guests, reran the installer, same thing. I used vmware article [1017838](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1017838) to uninstall v3 manually, reboot, and then drag the Fusion 4 app to the Applications folder. Reboot and run Fusion. Same thing. Checked /var/run for vmware items. Checked Activity Monitor for vmware items. Rechecked locations specified in [1017838](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1017838) and used spotlight to search around.

I moved all my guests to an extra drive and unmounted that drive, and repeated the uninstall and reinstall.  A friend recommended an app called "CleanApp" to watch what files are created and modified during the installs, which did reveal a bit more cruft. Basically, I've tried to scrub my system of all things Fusion, both versions including guests, and then done a reinstall, and that hasn't worked. My last gasp was booting into the 32 bit kernel but that didn't help.

I've filed a ticket with VMware, but it's been a slow slog.

Comment: It is not immediate obvious to me in your description above, but did you run the uninstall from 3.1.3?  I see that you manually removed it, but what about running the uninstaller?

Comment: I've attempted to clarify the question based on your comment and TheWellington's point about simply dragging the app icon to the Application Folder. I've done it both ways. First time, I ran the Upgrade 'installer' in the dmg. The first step of that is to trigger a uninstaller. When I got stuck there, I found 1017838 whose first step is to run the uninstall app found in 3.1.3. The stand alone 3.1.3 uninstaller also reports the same error.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this command from a Terminal:

**VMware 3.x**

`/Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Fusion/vmrun list`

**VMware 4.x**

`/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun list`

to see if you have any VMs runnig - if you do, then run this command:

**VMware 3.x**

`/Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Fusion/vmrun -T fusion stop "/path/to/.vmx" hard`

**VMware 4.x**

`/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun -T fusion stop "/path/to/.vmx" hard`

where you replace `"/path/to/.vmx"` with your path to the VM still running.

Answer (score 2):

Fusion uses [lock files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_file#Lock_files) to prevent multiple processes from modifying the same files at the same time, as could happen if you tried to run to copies of Fusion (say version 3 and version 4) at once.  When Fusion quits abnormally it leaves behind the lock files and you need to clean them up manually.

See [this support article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1019357) for how to check for running VMs and clean up Fusion lock files. If that doesn't solve it, do a Spotlight search including system files for files whose names end in `.lck` and if they look like they belong to Fusion, delete them.  You may find some lurking in your user home directory.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, the .dmg that contains the vmware installer contained several items...  one was a drag & drop VMware install.  You know the kind, drag to applications and be done.

One of the other items, that I had to scroll to find (love the invisible scrollbars in Lion) was an installer .pkg file that simultaneously uninstalled Fusion 3, and installed Fusion 4.  I don't recall what it was called.  Have you tried this .pkg?

I ask because you refer to two steps, and I distinctly recall only one step to do the upgrade.  I ran the .pkg and Fusion 3 was removed and 4 was installed.  I didn't need to take any additional steps.

It may be too late to try that method now, with all that you have done to remove Fusion 3...   but give it a try.